# Why am I only getting two options in systemd-boot?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, dual-boot

I set up an Arch USB stick, following the instructions given at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#In_Windows_2, section 1.2.2.  Specifically, I extracted the Arch ISO on to the drive and then installed syslinux on it, within Windows.

When I try to boot from the drive, I get to a menu with two options:

```
EFI Default Loader
Reboot into Firmware Interface
```

The first option just reloads the same menu, while the second goes into the Firmware Interface, as it says, and then boots Windows.

From looking around on the internet, it looks as if I've arrived at the systemd-boot menu (not Syslinux?) and that I should be seeing an option to boot into Arch above those two.

Clearly, I've done something wrong along the way.  At the moment, though, I have no idea what could be causing those menu items not to appear.  What do I need to fix?

Comment: The Arch ISO is prepared to be directly copied, with no need to install a bootloader. You should recreate the USB stick (preferably with `dd` or `dd` for Windows) and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably too late (or already solved) for the OP, but if anyone else trips over this like I just did:
Besides installing systemd-boot, you also need to manually add the boot entry for Arch, by creating a file at `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`.

See [this ArchWiki Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot#Standard_root_installations) for more information.

It's easy to miss that part, thanks to the large notice "bootctl will automatically check for..." making you think you're already done.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think I got round the problem in the end by using a different method, but I hope that this can help someone else.